# Validacion sin error JavaScript

Tags: javascript

existe alguna manera de validar este objeto sin usar try...catch?
Quiero comprobar la existencia de ese 'showScroll' que es un booleano y es una propiedad del objeto 'gear' dentro del objeto 'config'

```
if (config.gear.showScroll) { return true};
```

Da error por que 'gear' es undefined, usando try y devolviendo catch {} funciona pero no se si es lo correcto.
Otra forma, sin que de error, pero tampoco la que quiero es haciendo doble comprobación de la siguiente manera:

```
if (config.gear && config.gear.showScroll) { return true};
```

pero no es lo que quiero.
Tampoco quiero cargarlo previamente. Es simple, si no existe config.gear.showScroll que vaya por false.
Gracias

Comment: Esta es una pregunta basada en opiniones. Sinceramente la forma más elegante para hacerlo es la doble comparación que adjuntas y de hecho es la más extendida. No veo el problema en una sentencia de más. Nunca he visto a nadie usando un try..catch para algo como eso y de hecho se me hace bastante raro. Una sintaxis más moderna es el [`Optional chaining`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining), que quedaría algo cómo `if(config?.gear?.showScroll)`. Úsalo con [precaución](https://caniuse.com/mdn-javascript_operators_optional_chaining).

Comment: Jaime. Entiendo por qué decides poner un comentario en lugar de una respuesta, sin embargo, esa es la respuesta correcta. el optional chaining. En el sitio en español no hay ninguna otra pregunta relacionada con eso, y creo que una respuesta bien informada, como la tuya, puede ser valiosa para el sitio. Conviértela en respuesta y seguramente tendrás mi voto

Comment: Este fiddle demuestra lo que Jaime quiere decir: https://jsfiddle.net/3x0f2dw9/1/

Comment: *Pero no es lo que quiero...* Considera que programar no es un capricho o cuestión de gustos. Si `gear` puede ser `undefined` entonces debes verificar esa posibilidad antes de intentar usarlo o de acceder a una eventual propiedad suya. La verificación debe hacerse teniendo en consideración todo lo que puede ser o no ser y eso ya depende de la realidad de tus datos: ¿puede ser también `null`, puede ser también vacío? etc. Según esa realidad, escribe tu código, no según lo que te guste o no te guste. [Aquí hay varias respuestas](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2647867/5587982) que pueden ayudarte.

Comment: Muchas gracias jaime. Concuerdo, ponelo como respuesta.

Comment: Muchas gracias @Arriel y BCBB, ya agregué la respuesta.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Desde la salida del estándar `ECMAScript 2020` es posible utilizar el [operador de encadenamiento opcional](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) `?.` que evita que se lance una excepción si la propiedad anidada no existe.

Este operador en lugar de lanzar un error, retorna `undefined` si la propiedad no existe. Ten en cuenta que es una introducción relativamente nueva al lenguaje y no está [soportado por navegadores antiguos](https://caniuse.com/mdn-javascript_operators_optional_chaining), por lo que conviene usarlo junto a algo como `babel` o `typescript`.

En tu caso la sintaxis se reduciría a:

```js
function hasShowScroll(config){
   if(config?.gear?.showScroll) {
      return true
   } else{
      return false
   }
}

console.log(hasShowScroll({}))
```

O bien de manera más compacta:

```js
function hasShowScroll(config){
   return !!config?.gear?.showScroll
}

console.log(hasShowScroll({}))
```

Ten en cuenta que si no estás usando ningún tipo de transpilación, para dar soporte a la mayor cantidad de navegadores conviene usar la **doble comprobación** que adjuntas en tu pregunta. No recomiendo que uses el `try...catch`. Además de que no va a ser tan óptimo como una simple comprobación (lo cual no interesa en la mayoría de los casos), agregas anidamientos y complejidad a tu código sin razón alguna.

Comment: Excelente! Interesante inclusión del *bang, bang, you're boolean*.